# Как правильно использовать Theme.Material?

Tags: android, material-design, android-themes, android-appcompat

Пишу для api >= 21 и не хочу поддерживать старые версии. AppCompat, как я понял, существует для того чтобы material design работал на старых версиях android.
Получается я не должен его использовать.

Если я использую тему Theme.Material, я должен наследоваться не от AppCompatActivity, а просто Activity.

Но, например, CoordinatorLayout в своем конструкторе вызывает проверку

```
ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(context);
```

и если это не так, то бросает Exception.
Как использовать этот виджет, если наследуешься от Theme.Material?

Еще если наследоваться от Theme.Material, Android Studio использует другие шаблоны activity. Если сгенерировать navigation drawer activity, то будет сгенирована activity и NavigationDrawerFragment. Но почему? Ведь есть для этого NavigationView ?

Comment: Видимо нет никакой возможности использовать библиотеку *Support Design* без библиотеки *AppCompat*, с этим нужно либо смириться, либо отказаться и от библиотеки поодержки Design тоже.

Comment: `NavigationView` часть `com.android.support:design`, а она зависит от `com.android.support:support-v4`, а она зависит от `com.android.support:support-compat`, круг замкнулся.